# Get current load on Android device battery

Tags: android, batterylevel

I need the current load that is on the Android device battery. I know how to get the current battery output voltage and current battery level but can't figure out how much load the device is currently putting on the battery. For example I want the load on the battery before launching Google Maps, and then later want to see the load on the battery after launching google maps.

Is there a way I can do this? Any help would be great!

Comment: Would measuring the change in level over a period of time (a very short period of time) give you what you're looking for?

Comment: yes it would but as far as my understanding goes, Android's Battery Manager only registers battery levels in 1% changes. Is there a way I can get a more precise battery level?

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to get the current battery output voltage

No, you know how to get the battery output voltage at some point in time. Voltage levels change very quickly; the value you get from, say, `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` was the level at the point in time that `Intent` was constructed, not the point in time when you get a chance to examine that `Intent`.

> and current battery level

See above.

> but can't figure out how much load the device is currently putting on the battery

My understanding that this is possible using a voltmeter and working with the battery leads, though how easy this is to do probably depends upon the hardware (e.g., if the battery is non-removable, you may not be able to get to the leads).

*Some* hardware, like the Qualcomm MDP series, may have additional instrumentation to let you measure the current being supplied by the battery (which is what I assume you mean by "load").

Comment: I need the information within an app. Using any external hardware is no good. So I assume there is no way to check the actual load on the battery at any point in time?

Comment: @ArunKumar: Not on arbitrary hardware through the Android SDK. I have no idea if there are any Linux hacks you can try and whether they will be accurate/reliable.